# How do I smoothly complete an active css animation on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I've got this planet orbit code and what I'm *trying* to do on hover is to speed up the animation, have it complete one final animation cycle (at this new speed), and then stop. I figured how to get it to speed up on hover (apply a new animation on a parent class) but I cannot figure out how to get it to stop *after* one cycle has completed and return to its starting point. play-state doesn't work, because it's too abrupt, and I can't seem to just set a new iteration-count. I've tried using JavaScript but I'm having some trouble figuring it out so I'd love some help.

```css
.wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-125px;
    margin-top:-65px;
    height:250px;
    width: 250px;
    animation:orbit 2s linear;  
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-play-state: paused;
 
    
}

#orbit {
    height:250px;
    width: 250px;   
    z-index:1;
    border: 1px solid #989898;
    border-radius: 225px;
    animation:orbit 14s linear infinite;
  transform-origin:center center;
}
#planet {
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:5%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index:2;
    transform-origin:center center;
    background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.wrapper:hover{
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes orbit {
    100% {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="orbit">
        <div id="planet"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please just post your code as a Code Snippet, right here in your question, rather than link to external sites.

Comment: I think what you want to do is add a class on hover with javascript that overwrites `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Answer (score 0):

If you just overwrite the `animation-iteration-count` in your `:hover` class, you'll get one orbit at the new speed. Then, you'll need to set up an event handler for when the mouse leaves the `wrapper` that stops everything.

```js
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  // Change the wrapper to only animate one more time
  this.style.animationIterationCount = "1";
  
  // Remove the anmiation on the orbit
  document.getElementById("orbit").style.animation = "none";
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-125px;
    margin-top:-65px;
    height:250px;
    width: 250px;
    animation:orbit 2s linear;  
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;   
}

#orbit {
    height:250px;
    width: 250px;   
    z-index:1;
    border: 1px solid #989898;
    border-radius: 225px;
    animation:orbit 14s linear infinite;
  transform-origin:center center;
}
#planet {
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:5%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index:2;
    transform-origin:center center;
    background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.wrapper:hover{
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-iteration-count: 1; /* Just overwrite the iteration count */
}

@keyframes orbit {
    100% {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="orbit">
        <div id="planet"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to still restart the original animation when you hover out as well?

Comment: This solution works well for the first hover, but seems to have many flaws. As already stated, mousing off doesn't resume the original orbit. You could easily fix this, but when hovering over the element a second time the hover effect wouldn't run, because that animation has already reached its iteration count. You could reset that on mouse out too, but then mousing off mid-animation would cause the particle to teleport to a new location. I can't think of an elegant solution using only CSS animation. Coding this interaction properly may require using JS to drive the animation dynamically.